# Can I delete the {....} folders in my c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

Tags: windows-xp

Can I safely delete the folders with a `{<GUID>}`-name in the `c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data` folder?

Or are they needed by some uninstall programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These folders probably contain data needed by programs you've installed. If you search for the GUID in the registry you should find details of what program these are linked to.

If you can't find the GUID then there's a good chance that the software that does use these folders has been uninstalled, but it's not 100% certain.